# wpf using down arrow on combobox inside datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a Datagrid with a ComboBox inside. However once the cell gets selected the down arrow (from the keyboard) doesn't work to change the selection of the ComboBox.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ModelDisplayTemplate" DataType="vm:OrderObject">
         <Label Content="{Binding ModelName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Label>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ModelEditingTemplate" DataType="vm:OrderObject">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding modelList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValue="{Binding Model, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

I have tried to add `PreviewKeyDown` event and handle it as following:

```
    private void ComboBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            ComboBox s = e.Source as ComboBox;
            if (s != null)
            {
                s.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            }

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

However this function is not triggered when using the down arrow key. 
Also tried to use `PreviewKeyUp` instead but this also doesn't trigger the function.

Could it be that the ComboBox doesn't get the focus, so that's why the down arrow key doesn't work?

Comment: I believe the convention is ALT+down arrow.

Comment: If your combobox is actually there rather than a label, you're in edit mode and the combo has focus then you should be able to change between options with the up down arrow. I guess one of those criteria is not true. You might find this more reliable if you just have a combo in the celltemplate and don't switch between the label and combo or just use a comboboxcolumn.

Comment: I managed to get the focus on the ComboBox by using the `Loaded` event, when the event triggered I focussed on the ComboBox. This was indeed the missing criteria, after that the up and down button worked. The `PreviewKeyDown` was not needed in the end.